# How to bulk calculate and assign values to a column from another in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I got a table with 400 rows where I would like to bulk assign values.

There are these two columns: *columnpi2* and *columnm2*.

For each rows I would like *columnm2* values to use this logic:

```
columnpi2 X 0.09290304 if columnm2 != 0
```

How should I proceed ?

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1;
UPDATE table  SET columnm2=columnpi2*0.09290304 WHERE columnm2 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: `columnpi2 X 0.09290304` what does `X` symbolise here...?

Comment: I couldn't read it as a pseudo-code either.

Comment: Just `UPDATE table SET columnm2=columnpi2*0.09290304 WHERE columnm2 != 0.0` (By the way one would expect WHERE columnm2 IS NULL = not filled in)

Comment: What happens when you run the update statement? It looks like it should work, except that zero is not the same as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want change value on your table update it:

```
UPDATE table
    SET
        columnm2 = CASE WHEN columnm2 != 0 THEN columnpi2 * 0.09290304 ELSE 0
```